# How to use correlationBF() with multiple columns?

Tags: r, correlation, bayesian, psych

Could correlationBF() from BayesFactor package be used with multiple columns like the example below, corr.test() from psych package:

```
df <- data.frame (height  = c(1.95, 1.88, 1.91, 1.71, 1.57, 1.77),
              weight = c(82, 90, 88, 54, 38, 52),
              bmi = c(21, 25, 24, 18, 15, 16))

corr.test(df[1], df[2:3])
```

Currently, I need to specify each relationship which would be inefficient if there's lots of relationships to examine:

```
correlationBF(df$1, df$2)

correlationBF(df$1, df$3)
```

Trying to extend the code results in an error:

```
correlationBF(df[1], df[2:3])

Error in correlationBF(df[1], df[2:3]) : 
  Length of y and x must be the same.
```

Comment: Please confirm you are using the `BayesFactor` package, and please always be explicit about non-base packages in SO questions. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans confirmed both packages, thanks.